# Changing value on a label with UISlider control in WePopoverControler

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am in a process of implementing `WePopovercontroller` in my app and I have a question on how to implement uislider on it.  I am able to show the slider in the `UIView` and get the action when slider moved but not sure how to set the value of the label in that view. Here is the part of the code

```
-(void)popoverSliderMoved:(UISlider *) sender{
    NSLog(@"slider %f",sender.value);
}
```

---

```
-(IBAction)showSettingsMenu:(UIButton *)sender{

if(!self.popoverSettingsController) {
    // Create a label and button for the popover
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
    [label setText:@"Bookmark it!"];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [label setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 45, 100, 40)];
    [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(popoverSliderMoved:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
    [label setFont:font];
    CGSize size = [label.text sizeWithFont:font];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width + 10, size.height + 10); // add a bit of a border around the text
    label.frame = frame;

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:label.frame];
    [button addSubview:label];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(popoverButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIViewController *viewCon = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [viewCon.view addSubview:slider];
    [viewCon.view addSubview:button];
    CGRect popOverFrm = CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width + slider.frame.size.width, frame.size.height + slider.frame.size.height);
    viewCon.contentSizeForViewInPopover = popOverFrm.size;//CGSizeMake(100, 36);


    NSLog(@"Label Frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(label.frame));
    NSLog(@"Popover size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(viewCon.contentSizeForViewInPopover));
    NSLog(@"ViewCon: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(viewCon.view.frame));

    self.popoverSettingsController = [[WEPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewCon];


    //[self.popoverSettingsController setDelegate:self];
} 

if([self.popoverSettingsController isPopoverVisible]) {
    [self.popoverSettingsController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
   // [navPopover setDelegate:nil];
    self.popoverSettingsController = nil;
} else {

    [self.popoverSettingsController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(sender.frame.size.width, 0, 200, 57)
                                inView:self.navigationController.view
              permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp | UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown
                              animated:YES];
}
}
```

Would i need to use a delegate in this case or a property for this viewcontroller to set the label.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score -1):

Yes using a property would be what I would do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I did get it to work with properties but I am not sure if it's clean code to use properties and create uiview with it.  @ElDeveloper thanks for fixing my post.  Couldn't figure out why copy paste didn't put all he code in the code window.  I guess i had to separate functions

Comment: I agree. However I do not have that privilege yet.